# Get rid of boot priority changed press f1 to continue message

Tags: boot, bios

When I boot up my computer and my phone is charging or something via usb, a message comes up that forces me to press f1 to continue, due to the boot priority changing. I'm on a nforce 750i motherboard from evga and can't find a way to turn it off in the bios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this.  I have the same motherboard.  The reason it pops up is that a new mass-storage device has been detected - similar to if you changed the hard drives or added a new one.

What phone is it?  Try connecting the phone NOT in "mass-storage" mode, and see what happens.

Another possibility is to disable the "Keyboard wait on error" setting in the BIOS...

Comment: I have a g1, and I don't have usb mode turned on with it. I'll try the keyboard wait on error setting.

Comment: You should be able to tell the motherboard not to boot from usb in the bios.